# Cannot figure out how to respond to choices with embeds

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command, slash

```
    const ms = require('ms');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { ApplicationCommandType, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'guide',
    description: 'A guide of everything you need to know!',
    voiceChannel: false,
    options: [
    {
        name: 'guide',
        description: 'Select a guide to continue',
        type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
        required: true,
        choices: [
            {
                name: "data",
                value: "guide_data"
            },
            {
                name: "codebean",
                value: "guide_code",
                description: "A guide on CodeBean"
            }
        ]
    }
    ],

async execute({ inter }) {

const DataGuide = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor('#5679EF')
.setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }) })
.setTitle(' Guide')
.setDescription("How we use your data and how to prevent us from using your data")
.setFooter({ text: 'Powered by Nonay', iconURL: inter.member.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })});

const CodeBean = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor('#5679EF')
.setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }) })
.setTitle(' Guide')
.setDescription("code things")
.setFooter({ text: 'Powered by Nonay', iconURL: inter.member.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })});

    const adata = inter.options.getChoice('guide_data');
    const acode = inter.options.getChoice('guide_code');

    switch (adata) {
    case 'data':
    await inter.reply({ embeds: [DataGuide] })
    
}

    switch (acode) {
    case 'codebean':
    await inter.reply({ embeds: [CodeBean] })

}
},
};
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is provide people with a guide of what to do with my bot but I cant figure out how to use choices and how to respond to a certain choice that gets selected (for example, someone selects 'data' and gets a guide about their data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what you have typed in is correct actually. There's just two mistakes. When you declare choices for an option, you have to give it a `name` property and a `value` property. The `name` property tells what the choice would look like on the app and the `value` property is what you would receive if the user selected the option. You also seem to have misunderstood that choices are not another option by itself. It just gives a few hardcoded choices for the user to select from if the command had a string option. So, there isn't anything called as `getChoice()` So, your fixed code would look like this:

```js
const ms = require('ms');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { ApplicationCommandType, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'guide',
    description: 'A guide of everything you need to know!',
    voiceChannel: false,
    options: [
    {
        name: 'guide',
        description: 'Select a guide to continue',
        type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
        required: true,
        choices: [
            {
                name: "data",
                value: "guide_data"
            },
            {
                name: "codebean",
                value: "guide_code",
                description: "A guide on CodeBean"
            }
        ]
    }
    ],

async execute({ inter }) {

const DataGuide = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor('#5679EF')
.setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }) })
.setTitle(' Guide')
.setDescription("How we use your data and how to prevent us from using your data")
.setFooter({ text: 'Powered by Nonay', iconURL: inter.member.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })});

const CodeBean = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor('#5679EF')
.setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }) })
.setTitle(' Guide')
.setDescription("code things")
.setFooter({ text: 'Powered by Nonay', iconURL: inter.member.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })});

    const guide = inter.options.getString('guide'); // This gets whatever the user typed in for the guide option
    switch (guide) {
        case "guide_data": 
            await inter.reply({ embeds: [DataGuide] })
            break;
        case "guide_code": 
            await inter.reply({ embeds: [CodeBean] })
            break;
    }

},
};
```

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem, please accept the answer!

Comment: whoops sorry i didnt know how to do it